# When logging outside the except block, what are the ways to log the module name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

Suppose logging is done in an except block, then we can use `logging.exception("some message")`, and this will log the message along with the module name as part of the stack trace.

However, **when logging is done outside of the except block**, for example using logging.info, then one way to record the module name is using `__name__`. Example: `logging.info(f"some message here, in module: {__name__})`

Is there any other way in which we can log the module name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the log formatter attribute: `%(pathname)s`

Now any calls to logging will have the module name along with the log message.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes